# How to force tables to be in the middle of the page

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I am trying to include a set of tables into my document. Since the tables are quite large, I want them to be on landscape pages, and centered right in the middle of the page (that is, centered in terms of pagewidth and pageheight as well).

This works fine for the second to last table, however, the first table always ends up right on top of the page, which looks rather unpleasant.

The Tex code looks like following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\author{~~~}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=.01in, landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\input{../stata_outputs/regressions_page_length.tex}
\clearpage

\input{../stata_outputs/regressions_clicks.tex}
\clearpage

[...]

\end{document}
```

The input files are automatically generate by Stata, and en excerpt looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{page\_length after 0 weeks}
\begin{tabular*}{25cm}{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\extracolsep\fill}l*{5}{c}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}\\
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{control"}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{+local}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{+global}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{plus}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{all}\
[...]


\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize * p<0.10, ** p<0.05, *** p<0.010}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Is there any way that I could force Latex to put these tables exactly where I want them, preferrably by setting an option in the main file? Editing each individual input file is not really an option, since the are generated multiple times a day...

Comment: Can you set up Stata so that the tables it outputs have [p] positioner instead of [htpb]?

Comment: How come your tables are not centered? In the table environment there is the command `\centering` which centers them.. Or is this not the case in every table?

Comment: @Didii `\centering` is for horizontal placement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be OK if only `[p]` is specified as the positioning argument, because the contents of page of floats is always centered vertically.

If it's not possible to set up Stata so that it outputs `\begin{figure}[p]` for this particular document, then adding the following code to the preamble should force it anyway:

```
\let\latextable\table
\renewcommand\table[1][]{\latextable[p]}
```

Note: if you can convince Stata to say

```
\def\sym#1{\ensuremath{^{#1}}
```

your document will be more robust. This is one of the few cases when `\ensuremath` is really useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, altering the output from Stata is tedious, if not impossible. However, the first command that you suggested to me worked great.

Comment: @Benedikt That is not true. You are using Ben Jann's `estout` package which allows complete control over the `table` specifications, in your case using the `prehead(\begin{table}[p])` option. Close this off with the `postfoot(\end{table})` option.

Comment: Also thank you, Fg Nu. I flat out oversaw that option.